# XSRF-TOKEN in Angular

Tags: angularjs, token, csrf, csrf-protection

I have seen all kinds of different naming conventions for the XSRF-TOKEN.

What do I need to call the XSRF cookie when using AngularJS (without any other frameworks)?

Do I need to set the XSRF-TOKEN headers explicitly, like below, or does Angular do this for me if I give the cookie the right name?

```
$http.defaults.headers.post['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = $cookies.csrftoken;
```

The above assumes that I have named my cookie 'csrftoken'. If I call it 'XSRF-TOKEN', will Angular read this cookie automatically (assuming that ngCookies is loaded)? Or do I need the above code.

The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#cross-site-request-forgery-xsrf-protection) falls short on this critical point, as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Yes $http documentation is missing this point.

AngularJS looks for a cookie named "XSRF-TOKEN" and sets the header as "X-XSRF-TOKEN"